# Finding an unkown string within a string

Tags: python

This question is going to be similar, but looking for something completely different than one I asked a few days ago.

I have a string that is known, but is a portion of code, and it varies, I currently find it by using:

```
for num, line in enumerate(code, 1):
    if re.match("function (.*) {", line):
```

That gets me through a good portion of what I need, as I need to know the line number that it starts at. My problem starts here. What I need is just the part where I am using the **(.*)** regular expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean the text between `(` and `)`?

Use capturing groups:

```
m = re.match("function (.*) {", line):
if m:
  print m.group(1)
```

Comment: Yes, I do mean that text.

Answer (score 0):

The match object object which is returned contains all contents of groups.  I would use re.search if 'function' isn't always at the beginning of a line and '.+' to match functions with at least one character.

```
line_to_fn = {}

for num, line in enumerate(code, 1):
    match = re.search("function (.+) {", line)
    if match:
        matches = match.groups()
        assert len(matches) == 1, repr(matches)
        line_to_fn[num] = matches[0]

# line_to_fn: {1: 'something', 5: 'something_else'}here
```